# How can I Run Programs on Windows Login

Tags: script, login, login-items

I want to have certain programs and processes start up when I log in to Windows. These being Microsoft Edge (I have it open with a group of tabs I need to check for work), Microsoft Outlook, AutoHotKey scripts, Atlassian Hipchat and a few others.

What can I do to make this happen? I know that I can add things to group policy, or create bash scripts, but the specifics of this are beyond me. I am sure there is online documentation out there, but I am not sure which method I should use, or even which methods I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press and hold <kbd>Windows key</kbd> on the keyboard then press button <kbd>R</kbd> then type `shell:startup` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will get a new window, everything you will drop to this folder will run when you login in your account. It would be better if you will drop to this folder shortcuts to programs you want to start automatically. You can create shortcuts by making a right click on a program you want and choose "Create shortcut" from the menu.

Comment: Simple and easy. This is exactly what I need. Does this save per user? Is there a similar folder I could use for all users on the computer?

Comment: This solution applied to current user only. If you want this for all users, You need to create folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` that will serve the same purpose but for all users

Answer (score 0):

You could place entries for your applications under the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Notes:

- Use the existing entries as a guide.
- You can access this by running Regedit.exe and browsing down the tree.
- Be careful, if you feel you need to export the key you are changing to a reg file in order to undo your changes you can.

The other option might be to configure scheduled tasks, there are a couple of 'Triggers' that might be appropriate when you go through the wizard.

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` should be used for system wide operations. According to OS maker recommendations, such tasks should be created in `HKCU`   (HKEY_CURRENT_USER)

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to apply this to multiple users. (I would like to start outlook automatically for team members who log in to this computer after me since they are horrible at answering emails. haha) Anyway, this fits that need.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to your main question, but for the part of opening a group of tabs in the browser when it starts:

In Microsoft Edge you can automatically load specified pages (URL's) when it starts: - Settings -> Open With a specific page or Pages.

Comment: He asks about opening the program itself on PC startup

Comment: Yes but also about opening multiple urls in Edge, which the above didnt answer, thought this would be of help rather than answer the question fully. Every little advice helps I find. So dont really find the mark down appropriate.

Comment: You are correct. It is just not the answer.

Comment: Yisroel Tech - thanks for putting it and me right. I shall be more clear in future - new to answering, I'm usually the one asking the questions. :-)

Comment: No problem. Keep up trying to answer!